# C# Where is it better to put functions in a windows form, in the constructor after the components are initialised, the onLoad() event or Load() event

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I know this question has been asked before but that has been 10/11 years ago so I am wondering where it is faster and better to put the initial functions that you would want to run when the form has been loaded/created?

Comment: It depends a lot on what those function will do and if they are awaitable or not.

Comment: What about functions that set things up?

Comment: For what it worths with so many missing information I could only suggest to use the Shown event and make your function async

Comment: As a note, `OnLoad()` is not an event, it's the method responsible for raising the `Load` event. For the rest, all is highly dependable on what you're actually doing. Code that initializes Controls usually goes in the constructor, but it depends on what you're initializing and with what (e.g., the WebView2 initialization is not performed in the Parent Form's Constructor).

Comment: When would you use which is my question?